# NSIS write to a file on APPDATA inside a subdir

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to append 1 line of text into a file on the $APPDATA folder which is inside of a folder that's generated randomly, so I don't know it's full path like:

```
C:\Users\MyUser\AppData\Roaming\MyApp\RANDOM_CRAP\config.json
```

While `RANDOM_CRAP` looks like some random string for a folder, like `G4F6Hh3L`.

What are my options here? Do I need to use either [Search For a File](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Search_For_a_File) or [Search for a File or Directory (Alternative)](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Search_for_a_File_or_Directory_(Alternative)) ? **It's a given that the only subfolder of** `MyApp` **folder is the** `RANDOM_CRAP` **folder**, that contains the file I want to edit.

If there's no other way to access this file without searching for it, I've tried doing so but couldn't get this to work. (I'm very new to NSIS)

This is what I've tried (With the alternative approach):

```
Push "config.json"
Push "$APPDATA"
Push $0
GetFunctionAddress $0 "myCallback"
Exch $0
Push "1" ; include subfolders because my desired file is in the random folder
Push "0" ; no need the . option
Call SearchFile
```

Than I've copied the [SearchFile code from this post](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Search_for_a_File_or_Directory_(Alternative)) and put a callback:

```
Function myCallback
    Exch 3
    Pop $R4
    MessageBox MB_OK "Callback executing!"
    MessageBox MB_OK "File is at : $R4"
FunctionEnd
```

I know that `SearchFile` is running (I've put a MessageBox inside) but `myCallback` isn't seemed to be called.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a known file and only one directory in the path is unknown then you can probably just do a basic `FindFirst` search:

```
Section
; Create "random" folders:
CreateDirectory "$temp\MyApp\foo"
System::Call kernel32::GetTickCount()i.r1 ; random enough
CreateDirectory "$temp\MyApp\bar$1"
FileOpen $0 "$temp\MyApp\bar$1\config.json" a
FileWrite $0 '{bogus:"data"}$\n'
FileClose $0
CreateDirectory "$temp\MyApp\baz"

!include LogicLib.nsh
; Do the actual search:
StrCpy $9 "$temp\MyApp" ; The folder we are going to search in
FindFirst $0 $1 "$temp\MyApp\*"
loop:
    StrCmp $1 "" done
    ${If} ${FileExists} "$9\$1\config.json"
        DetailPrint "Found: $9\$1\config.json"
    ${EndIf}
    FindNext $0 $1
    Goto loop
done:
FindClose $0
SectionEnd
```